# How to stop inactivity timeout/onUserInteraction when doing the video on Android?

Tags: android, timeout

I am doing an app when there is no touch/interaction from the user, my app will shut down. But the problem is it is shut down even the videoing activity is on. So I would like to know if there is a way to prevent ON USER INTERACTION or how to stop call HANDLER.POSTDELAYED when video activity is on.
Thanks.
P/S: sorry for the uppercase but it shows grammar error if I typed in coding type.